# tabBarController memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uitabbarcontroller, nsarray

In my AppDelegate I initiate a tabBar Controller, to which a bunch of navigationController is added as tabs. I use the following code:

```
// Init tabBar Controller
tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] retain];

// Init Root Views of navigation controllers
FirstRootViewController* firstViewController = [[[FirstRootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
SecondRootViewController* secondViewController = [[[SecondRootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
ThirdRootViewController* thirdViewController = [[[ThirdRootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

// Init Navigation controllers of tabs
UINavigationController* firstNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController] autorelease];
UINavigationController* secondNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController] autorelease];
UINavigationController* thirdNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController] autorelease];

firstNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
secondNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
thirdNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

// Create array for tabBarController and add navigation controllers to tabBarController
NSArray *navigationControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = navigationControllers;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

And the dealloc function:

```
- (void)dealloc {
[window release];
[tabBarController release];
[super dealloc]; }
```

firstNavController are the navigation controllers to be added which are properly released altogether a few lines later (they are created using alloc).

TabBarController is a class variable which has been created using @property (nonatomic, retain) and @synthesize tabBarController. It receives a release command in the dealloc method.

Now instruments tells me that I have two memory leaks on the line with "tabBarController.viewControllers = navigationController".

I have tortured my head, yet I don't see why: From my understanding, navigationControllers should get released automatically and if I send it a release command a few lines later, the app crashes, so I guess I am right.

Any guesses whats wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post the complete code for allocating/deallocating the controllers and tabbar, there's nothing to read from this snippet.

Comment: I added the code you asked for, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `tabBarController` class variable has it's reference count increased twice. Once from the `alloc` and once from the `retain` in the first line of your code, yet is only released once in `dealloc` This is probably where your memory leak is coming from.

Secondly, although you have declared a matching `@property(nonatomic, retain) tabBarController` (and implemented via `@sysnthesize`) you are not actually using the property accessors (and its corresponding retain & release behaviour during assignment) To do this you need to use `self.tabBarController` rather than just `tabBarController` which will refer to the class variable, not the property.

Try modifying your code to the following to see if this solves your problem

```
// Init tabBar Controller
UITabBarController* tbc = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController = tbc;
[tbc release];
...

- (void)dealloc {
[window release];
self.tabBarController = nil;
[super dealloc]; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have changed the code in the way you proposed, yet I was not able to get it to work. I also do not quite understand the property vs. class variable thing: What are the main differences? So far I have always used @property and @synthesize to declare class variables.
I use the exact same code as you suggested, yet I still get the leak on the line where the Nav-/view Controllers are added. If I try to release them a few lines later, the app crashes (which also kind of makes sense as they should be available afterwards). Any ideas on that? Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Rather than explain it all here I suggest you read as mush as possible of Apple's Objective C programming reference http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf. The relevant sections to my answer are the chapter on 'Declared Properties' and the discussion of the use of self when accessing properties under 'Object Messaging'